# Mongoose and commander

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm writing some scripts for some command-line manipulation of [Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/) models with [commander.js](http://visionmedia.github.com/commander.js/) (eventually, I'd like to run these tools using [Cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)).

Now, I've written several scripts with `commander` and they all work fine, but if I connect to the MongoDB database using `mongoose`, they script just hangs after it's done.  Now, I figured the database connection is keeping node alive, so I added a `mongoose.disconnect()` line and it still hangs.

The only thing I found that allows me to shutdown is to use `process.exit()`, but I'm reluctant to just terminate the process.  Is there something in particular that I should do to trigger a graceful shutdown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shutdown the node program directly is hiding the symptoms, not fixing the problem!

I finally isolated the problem and found it to be with Mongoose schema definitions.  If you try to shutdown the connection too soon after Mongoose schemas are defined<sup>1</sup>, the application hangs and eventually produces some weird MongDB-related error.

Adding a small timeout before running the `program.parse(argv)` line to run the commander application fixes the problem.  Just wrap the code like so:

```
var program  = require('commander')
  , mongoose = require('mongoose')
  , models   = null
;

// Define command line syntax.
program
  .command(...)
;

mongoose.connect(
    ..., // connection parameters.

    function() {
        // connected to database, defined schemas.
        models = require('./models');

        // Wait 1 second before running the application code.
        setTimeout(function(){
            program.parser(process.argv);
        }, 1000);
    }
);
```

---

1: This is my initial interpretation, I have not (yet) extensively tested this theory.  However, removing Mongoose schema definitions from the application successfully prevents the application from hanging.

---

Actually, just using `process.nextTick()` instead of the `setTimeout()` call fixes the situation nicely!

Answer (score 0):

My reading of the [API docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html) implies that `.disconnect()` **must** be given a callback function. It looks like it's called for each  that's disconnected and may be passed an error.

There is a check in the code to make sure it's not called if it doesn't exist when things work out, but that check isn't being run on errors, so if Mongoose received an error message from the MongoDB client, it may be leaving a connection open and that's why it's not stopping execution.

If you're only opening a single connection to the database, you may just want to call `[Connection object].close()` since that function correctly inserts a no-op "callback" if no callback is given, and looks like it will correctly destruct things.

(The more I look into Mongoose, the more I want to just write a thin wrapper around the MongoDB client so I don't have to deal with Mongoose's "help.")

Comment: I don't get your first paragraph.  The API docs you link to clearly say: "**param:** *Function* optional callback".  Moreover, if I pass a `function(error){...}` or a `function(){...}`, I get a stack trace with "TypeError: object is not a function.".

Comment: They claim it's optional, but *read* the code on the right-hand side it's talking about. It doesn't check if the function was actually provided if there's an error that occurs. ``if(err) return fn(err)`` comes **before** ``if(fn)``.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I'm a slow reader :-)  I've added some more diagnostics and the connection is closed without an error (the `err` value is `undefined`).  However, I eventually get some other error from the MongoDB core so I don't know if this fixes my problem.  I'll keep in touch when I have more details.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your answer.  Unfortunately this doesn't solve the problem, but I'll report this bug in the Mongoose issue tracker.

Comment: I just [reported this issue](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues/875) on the Mongoose issue tracker.

Answer (score 0):

I use the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async/#series) "Series" to perform operations and then call *mongoose.connection.close()* on completion. It prevents callback hell and allows you to neatly perform operations either one at a time or parallel followed by a function when all the other methods have completed. I use it all the time for scripts that require mongoose but are meant to terminate after all mongoose operations are finished.